# Send Crash Reports from within App

Tags: iphone, reporting-services, crash

The FourSquare iPhone app seems to be doing it already: http://screencast.com/t/NjRkNmIwNWQ

How is this achieved? This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577034/how-to-send-email-when-an-app-crashes-on-the-iphone) pointed out [CrashReporter.framework](http://github.com/TheRealKerni/CrashReporterDemo), but isn't this the kind of 3rd party framework Apple doesn't allow in the App Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the framework answered me on twitter a few minutes after I posted this question:

> The
>   PLCrashReporter.framework only looks
>   like one, but isn't. Quite a few apps
>   are using it without issues. 4Square
>   is using also PLCrashReporter
>   framework, but sends out the reports
>   via email. So no automatic grouping on
>   server.

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing from the snippet you provided, but they may be using Plausible Labs' [Crash Reporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) (since their crashlog is a .plcrash file).

Comment: Good call, indeed they are. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to find out is to add a Boolean flag to your NSUserDefault instance:

In - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"FinishedSafely"];
```

In - `(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`

```
[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"FinishedSafely"];
```

You can then check against this key at launch time to see if the last instance was close properly and act accordingly.

Comment: This only tells whether the app closed nicely or not. What I want to do is send the crash report my way on next launch.

Comment: Sorry read the question a bit fast. I know three20 had some support for crash report althought those are good when you build with symbols (debug) but are quite useless for application build for production.